# Can not get access form from Script Editor - create edit form link

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using google apps script to create a link to a submitted form and add this link to the spreadsheet so people can amend the submitted form at a later stage using the link.

The script is as follows:

```
// Form URL
  var sheetName = 'Complete Overview';
  var columnIndex = 8;

function getEditResponseUrls() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Complete Overview');
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var form = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/FORMID/viewform');
     var finalUrl = null;
    for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex - 1] == '') {
            var timestamp = data[i][0];
            var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
            if (formSubmitted.length < 1) {
                continue
            } else {
                var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
                sheet.getRange(i + 1, columnIndex).setValue(editResponseUrl);
                finalUrl = editResponseUrl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return finalUrl
}

var editResponseUrlLink = getEditResponseUrls()
```

When I submit a form I get the error message "Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it."

I do have access to the form (it's on a shared drive, I tried to move it to my personal drive but this did not work), gave permission to Google to access the necessary documents and the URL is correct (this seemed to be the problem for other users).

Any ideas?

Comment: columnIndex is undefined

Comment: How is your ````columnIndex```` defined? Does it still return the same error (or a different one) if you define it?

Comment: and it seems the loop `for` does only one iteration and breaks by the return statement. It returns variable `finalUrl` that is undefined. That's the mess. Your function doesn't work at all

Comment: Columnindex is defined as 8, apologies I didn't include that part

var columnIndex = 8;